# accessing a private ip from another global ip

Tags: networking

i am a linux user and i am working on global ip say 202.212.56.215. Now i have a system whose authentication i know and its on private network ie its ip is 192.168.1.29 (assumption) on global ip say 217.34.32.213. Can i access that system through ssh or someother means??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access it without an intermediate computer, your only chance is to do some port forwarding on your router (port 22 is the standard one for SSH). Alternatively (if you have not that possibility) you could scan your router from the internet and find out what ports are already open. If there's one that is open and unused, you could configure SSH on your "private" computer to listen on that port rather than port 22.

Alternative methods imply the use of a globally accessible computer on which your private computer will be somehow permanently connected. You will have then to access this "middleman computer" in order to access your provate one. There are tons of how-to's online. Googling `ssh to a computer behind a router` will return about 1 million results.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to enable port forwarding for the ssh port (22 by default, but more secure if you configure it to use a non default port) on the router of the private network.

How to do that depends on which router it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would most likely have to access it via their "global ip" and set up port forwarding on the router to point to their private IP.